# Woocommerce: save_post hook is not being triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-boxes

I have a meta box I'm coding for the product post type that comes with woocommerce. I've run into a problem I can't pass in that the 'save_post' hook does not seem to be working at all with products. It works perfectly for posts, but since I've changed my code to work for products it does nothing. The save_post function I've hooked to does absolutely nothing at the moment. I've added all sorts of code to it and it doesn't matter, the script just doesn't seem to get that far. am I missing something obvious?

Edit: as an aside, I added

```
?> <script type="text/javascript">

            var post_id = '<?php $post_id ?>';
            console.log("id is: " +  post_id );
            </script><?php
```

But it returns absolutely nothing.

```
<?php
/*
*   Represents the plugin's Meta Box
*
*   @since          0.0.1
*   @package        BBPlugin
*   @subpackage     BBPlugin
*   @author         Christopher Dando <captaindando@gmail.com>
*/

/*
*   Represents the plugin's Meta Box
*
*   Register's the meta box with the WordPress API, sets its properties,
*   by including the markup from its associated view
*   
*   @package        BBPlugin
*   @subpackage     BBPlugin/admin
*   @author         Christopher Dando <captaindando@gmail.com>
*/

class BBPlugin_Meta_Box{

    /*
    * Register this class with the wordpress API
    * 
    * @since 0.0.1
    */
    public function initialize_hooks(){
        //add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_product', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'BBadd_meta_box' ) );

        // This checks when wordpress is saving or
        // updating a post.
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) ); 
        $junk = $post_id;
        ?> <script type="text/javascript">

            var post_id = '<?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>';
            console.log("id is: " +  post_id );
            </script><?php
    }


    // add_meta_boxes is the wordpress function. add_meta_box is our new function

    /*
    * The function responsible for creating the actual meta box.
    *
    * @since    0.0.1
    */
    public function BBadd_meta_box(){
        ?> <script>console.log("meta box added");</script><?php
        add_meta_box(
            'BBPlugin',
            "Brave Books",
            array( $this, 'display_meta_box' ),
            'product',
            'normal',
            'default'
        );
    }
    // This defines the properties of the meta box.

    /*
    * Renders the content of the meta box.
    *
    * @since    0.0.1
    */
    public function display_meta_box(){
        include_once( 'views/BBPlugin-navigation.php' );
    }


    /**
     * Sanitizes and serializes the information associated with this post.
     *
     * @since    0.0.1
     *
     * @param    int    $post_id    The ID of the post that's currently being edited.
     */

     // strangely, this calls if the meta box does not render
    public function save_post( $post_id ) {
        ?><script>alert("post saved");</script><?php
        /* If we're not working with a 'product' post type or the   
            user doesn't have permission to save,
            then we exit the function.
        */
        if ( ! $this->user_can_save( $post_id, 'BBPlugin_nonce', 'BBPlugin_save' ) ) {

            return;
        }

        /*
            We need to 'Sanitise' our information before 
            we can save it to the database. What this means
            is that we must strip it of html tags
            and extract the text itself.
        */

        // If the 'Resources' inputs exist, iterate through them and sanitize them
        if ($this->value_exists( 'BBPlugin-resources' ) ) {
            // This is all divs with the id of meta-box-resources
            $this->update_post_meta(
                $post_id,
                'BBPlugin-resources',
                $this->sanitize_data( 'BBPlugin-resources', true )
            );
        }
        else {
            // leaving an input blank on the front end will remove that specific input.
            $this->delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'BBPlugin-resources' );
        }

    }



    /**
     * Determines whether or not a value exists in the $_POST collection
     * identified by the specified key.
     *
     * @since   0.0.1
     *
     * @param   string    $key    The key of the value in the $_POST collection.
     * @return  bool              True if the value exists; otherwise, false.
     */
    private function value_exists( $key ) {
        return ! empty( $_POST[ $key ] );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the specified meta data associated with the specified post ID 
     * based on the incoming key.
     *
     * @since    0.0.1
     * @access   private
     * @param    int    $post_id    The ID of the post containing the meta data
     * @param    string $meta_key   The ID of the meta data value
     */
    private function delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key ) {
        if ( '' !== get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ) ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '$meta_key' );
        }
    }

    private function update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {   
        if ( is_array( $_POST[ $meta_key ] ) ) {
            $meta_value = array_filter( $_POST[ $meta_key ] );
        }
        /* 
            Update_post_meta also adds to a database if there is nothing there already.
            parameters are as follows:

            1. The post ID used to associate this information with the post.
            2. A meta key that's used to uniquely identify the value.
            3. The actual value associated with the meta key.
        */  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }

    /**
     * Sanitizes the data in the $_POST collection identified by the specified key
     * based on whether or not the data is text or is an array.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @access   private
     * @param    string        $key                      The key used to retrieve the data from the $_POST collection.
     * @param    bool          $is_array    Optional.    True if the incoming data is an array.
     * @return   array|string                            The sanitized data.
     */
    private function sanitize_data( $key, $is_array = false ) {
        $sanitized_data = null;
        if ( $is_array ) {
            $resources = $_POST[ $key ];
            $sanitized_data = array();
            foreach ( $resources as $resource ) {
                $resource = esc_url( strip_tags( $resource ) );
                if ( ! empty( $resource ) ) {
                    $sanitized_data[] = $resource;
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            $sanitized_data = '';
            $sanitized_data = trim( $_POST[ $key ] );
            $sanitized_data = esc_textarea( strip_tags( $sanitized_data ) );
        }
        return $sanitized_data;
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the post type that's being saved is actually a post (versus a page or another
     * custom post type.
     *
     *
     * @since       0.0.1
     * @access      private
     * @return      bool      Return if the current post type is a post; false, otherwise.
    */
    private function is_valid_post_type() {
        return ! empty( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'post' == $_POST['post_type'];
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether or not the current user has the ability to save meta data associated with this post.
     *
     * @since       0.0.1
     * @access      private
     * @param       int     $post_id      The ID of the post being save
     * @param       string  $nonce_action The name of the action associated with the nonce.
     * @param       string  $nonce_id     The ID of the nonce field.
     * @return      bool                  Whether or not the user has the ability to save this post.
     */
    private function user_can_save( $post_id, $nonce_action, $nonce_id ) {

        $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
        $is_revision   = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
        $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce_action ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce_action ], $nonce_id ) );

        // Return true if the user is able to save; otherwise, false.
        return ! ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) && $this->is_valid_post_type() && $is_valid_nonce;
    }






}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress, `save_post` isn't a destination in itself; it is an action carried out effectively 'between' pages: you hit **Update**, and Wordpress will carry out a series of actions behind the scenes before returning you to the appropriate page (invariably the post you were just editing, with a notification about the status of that save).

As such, you will never see the results of an `echo`, `print_r`, or JS `alert` or `console.log`, because `save_post` isn't a user-facing action.

If you want to see if your `save_post` action is being carried out in this way, I would recommend throwing in a `die()`, like so:

```
public function save_post($post_id) {
    ?><script>alert("post saved");</script><?php
    die();
}
```

If the `save_post` action is being fired correctly, then you should see the JS alert over a blank page. If you want to see if your function is carrying out any actual Wordpress-style functionality, I'd recommend a simple `update_post_meta` to confirm:

```
public function save_post($post_id) {
    // Insert some actual logic to ensure you're not doing this on every post all the time

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'i_am_saved', 'totes saved to post #' . $post_id);
}
```

You can then check the database (or click to view the custom fields within that post) to see if your custom metadata has been added.

I would also recommend attaching your `save_post` action *specifically* to the `product` post type that's used by WooCommerce:

`add_action('save_post_product', array($this, 'save_post'));`

That will save some redundancy checking later.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been wracking my brain for hours trying to get this to work

Comment: it seems that if I use the function wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );, it always comes back as false. is this related to the same problem?

Comment: @CaptainDando `wp_is_post_revision` will **always** return false _unless you're working on a post revision_. If you're just updating a regular post, `wp_is_post_revision` will return false - which is what you want. You need to update your logic to account for it returning false rather than true.